# Docker for private server

Tags: ubuntu, docker, gitlab, docker-compose, nextcloud

I want to set up a server (Ubuntu V-Server) for a few people. I'm planning to run a few applications e.g. GitLab, NextCloud, and Seafile.

What are the advantages of orchestrating these apps (and their dependencies like PostgreSQL) in containers via docker-compose, vs installing them directly on "bare metal" and configuring them by hand?